# How Accurate Is Google Places "Popular times"

Tags: google-maps

I own a gym, which is in the basement of a hotel and immediately next to a busy bus stop.

The "Popular times" on the Google listing for my gym don't appear to align with my experience. Is it likely Google is counting visits to surrounding locations and is there any way to disable this feature for my business, so I do not deter potential visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that Google is using the data of places immediately around you as they use location data for this feature. It uses information from users with their location data tracking turned on to determine this, and if that person is near your gym or above the gym, they are more than likely being included in those stats.

You unfortunately cannot disable or change this feature.

Some more information [here](https://www.technipages.com/how-does-google-know-if-a-place-is-busy).

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, my gym is next to a banquet hall. There have been times the gym was empty yet Google listed it as "much busier than normal" due to a wedding next door!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155877)